# Quivers, request for theorem of Dlab & Ringel of 1973

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras, quiver

Looking at Gabriel's theorem on [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel's_theorem) I found the following statement.

> Dlab & Ringel (1973) found a generalization of Gabriel's theorem in
>   which all Dynkin diagrams of finite-dimensional semisimple Lie
>   algebras occur.

The reference point to a book which is not available and that I couldn't find. Does anybody know the statement which Wikipedia is referring to?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

A better reference might be the following:

Dlab, V.; Ringel, C.M. Indecomposable representations of graphs and algebras. Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 1976, 6, v+57.

Also, the article [Valued Graphs and the Representation Theory of Lie Algebras](http://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/1/2/111/pdf) by Joel Lemay discusses this result.